# Converting REST API request from JSON to Calendar

Tags: java, jackson

Currently I have request from an API endpoint that comes in the below format.

```
 {"amount":"122.96","timestamp":"2019-05-28T12:19:54.702Z"}
```

I want to try and convert the timestamp to a Calendar object in the below resource.

```
 public class resource {

 @JsonProperty
 private BigDecimal amount;

 @JsonProperty
 private Calendar timeStamp;

 }
```

However the endpoint fails to map due to the following:

```
 java.lang.Error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.api.Resource]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.api.Resource` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

I tried adding a @JsonFormat and also @JsonDeserializer using a custom deserializer attached beloow

CustomDeserializer.class

```
public class CalendarDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Calendar> {

protected CalendarDeserializer() {
    super(Calendar.class);
}

public Calendar deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    c.setTimeInMillis(jp.readValueAs(Long.class));
    return c;
}
```

}

I expect to be able to map the timestamp correctly over to a calendar object

Comment: First, you need a constructor annotated `@JsonCreator` in your `Resource` class -- that is what exception complains about. Then, case must be followed in both json and DTO class  ("time**S**tamp" vs "time**s**tamp"), or you need to name the property explicitly

Comment: Ah! this solved the issue! apologies, my brain go so fried that I should of noticed ha thanks @alexSalauyou